# There is a nltk lemmatizer in spanish?

Tags: python, nltk, lemmatization

I want to process some text in oder to classify them in groups. What I need to do first is a good preprocessing of the data, I've been loocking in internet and the people recommend lemmatization over stemming. My text is in Spanish, although I have found in nltk a way to do stemming in spanish with SnowballStemmer('spanish'), I didn't find it with lemmatization with nltk, the other libraries that I have found to do lemmatization are not good as nltk with english. There is a way to use nltk lemmatization in Spanish?